# IP failover in cURL - is it possible?

Tags: php, curl, nginx, debian, failover

I have VPS on OVH, and I have one failover IP (eth0:0). Could you tell me, if It is possible to use this failover IP in cURL requests with PHP?

I tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0:0");
```

and:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

..but it doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I will try to help you here.

Can you try the following command and see if you get the correct results?

```
curl --interface eth0 http://ifconfig.me
curl --interface eth0:0 http://ifconfig.me
```

Check if the first one returns the correct IP for the device `eth0`, and the second one the correct IP for the device `eth0:0`.

The reason I am asking that is to try to figure out if the problem is with curl or on the OS (routing tables, etc).

Comment: It's not hard to get 50 reputation so you can comment. Postingcomments as answers is not part of that.

Comment: @Barmar Basically you are saying I should refrain from helping someone until I get some imaginary points? Even if I know that depending on his answer, I can point him on the right direction? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I didn't make the rules, but there must be a reason why they don't want <50 rep to comment.